# Vite + MailerSend error - process is not defined

Tags: reactjs, config, vite

Im trying to implement MailerSend package inside my vite react project, but getting error on production

vite.config.js

```
  export default ({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    define: {
      "process.env": env,
    },
    server: {
      host: "localhost",
      hmr: {
        clientPort: 5173
      },
    },
  });
};
```

in app.js when I just import it crashes

```
import { EmailParams, MailerSend } from "mailersend";
```

error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at V0 (index-8e47e207.js:134:1613)
at index-8e47e207.js:134:16404
```